# Rust lettre send email body as an encoded html

Tags: html, email, rust, base64

i wanto to send a base64 encoded html with lettre as the body of my email, it should be possible, but when i send it in the email body i see onlt base64 string instead of my html
in theory if i pass the header content-transfer-encoding base63 it should automatically render the base64 but for me it don't works, here my code:

```
    let email = Message::builder()
        .from(row.mail_from.parse()?)
        .to(row.mail_to.parse()?)
        .subject(row.mail_subject)
        .header(ContentType::TEXT_HTML)
        .header(ContentTransferEncoding::Base64)
        .body(row.mail_body)?;

    let creds = Credentials::new(smtp2go_username.to_owned(), smtp2go_password.to_owned());

    let mailer = SmtpTransport::relay(&smtp2go_server)
        ?
        .credentials(creds)
        .build();

    let result = mailer.send(&email);
    match result {
        Ok(_) => {
            info!("Email sent successfully to {} with from {}", row.mail_to, row.mail_from);
            // set the mail to sent
            let query = format!("UPDATE notifications_mail_queue SET mail_sent = 1 WHERE id = {}", row.id);
            conn.query_drop(query)?;
            // set the sent date
            let current_date = Local::now().to_rfc3339();
            let query = format!("UPDATE notifications_mail_queue SET mail_sent_date = '{}' WHERE id = {}", current_date, row.id);
            conn.query_drop(query)?;
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to send email to {} with from {}. Sending with {}: {:?}", row.mail_to, row.mail_from, smtp_username, e);
        }
    }
```